# Finding number of pair of sequences of length m and n such that their maxima are equal

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given three integers $n$ , $m$ and $X$ , find the number of pair of sequences consisting of values from 1 to $X$  such that **maximum element of both sequences are equal**.

**Note :** X is a large value and m and n are comparatively much smaller

Example : for $n$ = $2$ , $m$ = $2$ , $X$ = $2$

the following sequences could be generated :

[1 , 1] [1 , 1] 
[1 , 2] [1 , 2]
[1 , 2] [2 , 1]
[1 , 2] [2 , 2]
[2 , 1] [1 , 2]
[2 , 1] [2 , 1]
[2 , 1] [2 , 2]
[2 , 2] [1 , 2]
[2 , 2] [2 , 1]
[2 , 2] [2 , 2]

so in total  $10$ sequences could be generated.

 Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many single sequences can you generate that include the highest number?  Take all the sequences and subtract those that do not have the highest number.  The number of pairs is just the square of this.  Now add up all the values for each choice of highest number.

Comment: Yes that's obvious. But actually X is very large compared to m and n. so I cannot count for each highest from 1 to X , hence $\sum_{l=1}^{l=X}(l^n - (l-1)^n)*(l^m - (l-1)^m)$ will not work. Can we do it faster?

Comment: The exponents should be the same in both terms of your sum.  Now you can expand that and use the formulas for the sums of powers.

Comment: But why exponents would be same? n and m maybe different values? And can you please help me expanding it into individual sums of powers.

Comment: I didn't realize that $m,n$ were the lengths of each sequence.  You are right that they can be different.  You still get sums of powers $n+m$  For example, if $n=3,m=2$ the first term is $\sum l^5=\frac{2X^6+6X^5+5X^4-X^2}{12}$.  See [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: Hmm.. I am struggling to expand them into individual sums of powers

Comment: You could expand $(l-1)^n$, and $(l-1)^m$, then you have a string of powers of $l$ up to $l^{n+m-2}$

Comment: I tried expanding but now I am left with term :   $\sum_i$ ( $\binom{m}{i}$ + $\binom{n}{i}$ - $\binom{m+n}{i}$) * $l^{m+n-i} *(-1)^i$  and I have no idea how to apply sum of  powers with different coefficient of each term

Comment: You might get a formula in $X$ for $m=n=2$, or $m=2,n=3$.  Build up a list of results, there might be a trend.  I can't see how to get a general function of $n,m,X$ all at once.

Comment: To leading order, it is $\sum_l nml^{n+m-2}$, or approximately $nmX^{n+m-1}/(n+m-1)$

Comment: wow @Empy2  $\frac{nmX^{n+m-1}}{(n+m-1)}$ is so close to actual values. You are correct there must be some general function in $X$